# perl carton cpanfile, optional install into main perl environment

Tags: perl, cpan, cpanm

I have a carton cpanfile.  on servers on which I have sudo, I would be happy to install the latest versions of my modules globally instead.

do I write a script that removes the 'requires' and uses `cpan -i` (although I am concerned that I may have too many to fit the command line limit), or is this functionality already somewhere else?

Comment: If there is a cpanfile you can just run `cpanm --installdeps .` as root in the directory with the cpanfile and cpanm will read it and do the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a [cpanfile](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Module-CPANfile/lib/cpanfile.pod) you can just run

```
$ cpanm --installdeps .
```

as root (with `sudo`) in the directory with the cpanfile and [`cpanm` will read it](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm#-installdeps) and install your dependencies to whatever Perl is configured for this `cpanm`.

You can ignore `carton` for that completely.

Comment: Anyone switching from carton install to use this should note that carton install by default does not run the tests (--notest) so what used to be a clean install might suddenly not be so.
https://github.com/perl-carton/carton/issues/159
https://github.com/perl-carton/carton/issues/205

Comment: My mention of "by default" is misleading as there is no option (yet) to run carton with tests
https://github.com/perl-carton/carton/pull/145